# How to run jenkins pipeline job with docker commands in stand alone Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline script which creates the Docker image and deploys it to the docker hub. I have installed the docker plugin but it complains about **"docker command not found"**. I am not sure if I need to install docker in the same machine or something else need to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to install docker on the slave machine which is running that pipeline script of docker plugin. I would suggest adding a label `docker` to the slave that has docker installed and then use the pipeline script as:

```
node('docker') {
...
}
```

Comment: thanks! I am not really running the pipeline on the slave machine. I'm running the Jenkins build in the same standalone machine. So it means that I need to install the Docker in the same machine where Jenkins is?

Comment: @SameerMalhotra correct. the `docker pipeline` plugin is just a wrapper that calls the `docker` commands under the hood.