# Jenkins pipeline issue with Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I was trying to run a Jenkins pipeline project, it failed giving this message under the "docker pull node:6-alpine":

```
<.jenkins/workspace/simple-node-js-react-npm-app@tmp/durable-431710c5/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found

script returned exit code 127>
```

I have no idea what's going on here, and I couldn't access the directory mentioned in the error. I am pretty new to Jenkins.

Comment: Did you installed docker on host machine, or configured docker in Jenkins??

Comment: Looks like Docker is not installed. What OS are you using for your Jenkins box?

Comment: @sanath I did install docker on host machine but not sure how it is different from configure docker in Jenkins...

Comment: @halfer I did install docker and I'm using macOS. Don't know if installing the docker app on macOS count as installation for Jenkins...

Comment: It depends on whether that's Docker itself, or just a Docker client - I would guess the latter. What do the instructions on the Docker website suggest?

Comment: @halfer I believe it tells me to pull images as needed...

Comment: No, you need to install Docker first - you can't pull an image without the `docker` command. Search for "how to install Docker on OS X" or similar. If you believe you have installed Docker already, please edit your question to describe how you did that.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45489924/6309), using the [JENKINS Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) or [JENKINS Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) would not be enough to allow a node to use docker.
You still need to install docker on the node itself.

Comment: Thank you but not sure how to install docker on node... Really appreciate if you can be more specific!

Comment: @Harryz Then you need to check the PATH environment variable after running a dummy job: does it include the docker installation path?

Comment: Does your Jenkins and docker resides on same host? or do you using 2 hosts one for Jenkins and another host as node for Jenkins.

Comment: @sanath They are on the same host

Comment: @VonC Thank you for the suggest! Let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Install the docker engine (`yum install docker`) on server where `Jenkins` is running.
2. Verify `docker` is installed: run command `which docker`.
3. Click on Jenkins manage plugin and install docker plugin.